# Download a File using webrequest.create c# via redirected link

Tags: c#

I am trying to download a file from a page that redirects itself using JS.
For example: https://wix.codeplex.com/downloads/get/119160
When that page is loaded in the browser the file download starts automatically using a JS function.
But when I try to download it using webrequest.create I only get the HTML of that page (119160).

Is there any clean way to download the file without inspecting the html/js manually?

Thanks,

Comment: Your browser is already inspecting these things in detail in order to make the download happen. Why would you expect your own process to be able to skip all this without itself creating a full web browser?

Comment: Hello Joel, well my goal isn't creating a web browser. I simply need to download a file from an URL

Answer (score 0):

Could use [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control (which can handle JS execution) then subscribe to the [FileDownload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.filedownload(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

For a little earlier notice, you could subscribe to [Navigating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating(v=vs.110).aspx) (which should get triggered once the JS kicks in).

Comment: Hello Brad, using the WebBrowser control seems as a hack, which it is not a very clean solution